# loop to paste specific files in different directories

Tags: shell, text-processing, wildcards

I some directories that contain a similarly named file eg (*Sample_name*.base.coverage.txt).  And I would like to paste all of the *base.coverage.txt files together. I have something written, but its not quite right as I don't think I am actually pasting them together.

```
cd /g/bo/vir/analysis
find -type d  |
while read dir; do
if [ -f $dir/*.base.coverage.txt ]; then
    paste  $dir/*.base.coverage.txt >> paste_all_l30.p90.base.cov.norm

fi
done
```

I am also thinking of a different  loop method, but I am unsure how to get the list of directories into an array.

```
for x in $dir; do cat /$x/*.base.coverage.txt;done > paste_all_l30.p90.base.cov.norm
```

Any help?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.base.coverage.txt" -exec sh -c 'paste {} paste_all_l30.p90.base.cov.norm > tmp ; mv tmp paste_all_l30.p90.base.cov.norm' \;
```

Comment: Hmm, snap! (almost)

Comment: Thanks, but this also just yields a file with one column.

Comment: Try to change `cat` to `paste` like I did in my answer. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: find . -type f -name "*.fastx.allbest.l30.p90.base.cov.norm" -exec paste {} > paste_all_l30.p90.base.cov.norm\ ;
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: That's not going to work anyway because appending to the file is the wrong thing.

Comment: seems like space is in the wrong place. use `\;` in the end instead `\ ;`. and yeap, ams is right. i've just fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.base.coverage.txt' \
  | xargs paste > paste_all_l30.p90.base.cov.norm
```

This will work as long as there are not too many files. If there are a lot of file then this:

```
touch paste_all_l30.p90.base.cov.norm
for file in `find . -type f -name '*.base.coverage.txt'`; do
  paste paste_all_l30.p90.base.cov.norm $file > tmp
  mv tmp paste_all_l30.p90.base.cov.norm
done
```

Comment: The OP wants to *[paste](http://ss64.com/bash/paste.html)*, not `cat`

Comment: Ok, I missed that. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to recurse through a number of directories would be to write a short python script and use the `os.path.walk` function to recurse through the nested directories. For appending, you could use `shutil.copyfileobj` within the loop, checking filenames with a regex.